# Converting Webpage into image using javascript

Tags: javascript, screenshot, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

I am having 1 webpage in which I am getting some details from db in the form of table I want that page to be saved as an image so that that image I can mail it to the user.Can anybody help me out please

Answer (score 1):

javascript in the webrowser for security reasons doesn't have the ability to do something low level like take a screenshot of the users screens. You can take a [screenshot with something like selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

[Marwan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699750/marwan-alsabbagh) is right. Security issues prevent that for javascript. I would send a request to server with will generate the pic, and then send back the image. This of course increases the CPU & network usage of your server.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [HTML 2 Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) which can render some parts of the DOM into a canvas. However, this might only work on in a browser allowing you to use canvas objects as they are part of the HTML5 specification.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it with JS, generally can't make any screenshots.